# Export result to csv and print it in one column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export-to-csv, export-to-excel

I have the following code, where I predict if it is going to rain the next day. As result I get 1 or 0.

```
weatherbayes = GaussianNB()
weatherbayes.fit(X_train, y_train)
predbayes = weatherbayes.predict(df_test)
data = [predbayes]
print(data)
np.savetxt("student.csv",data, newline =" ", delimiter = '\t',  fmt ='% s')
```

I get following result:
[image]

data shape: (1, 11540)

**But I need to print it in one column and for each value a row.**

Comment: What is the shape of data? `data.shape`

Comment: @Corralien (1, 11540)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your shape is (1, 11540) and you want one value per row, transpose your array.

```
# data = np.random.choice([0, 1], (1, 10))
# data.shape -> (1, 10)
np.savetxt('student.csv', data.T, fmt='%d')
```

Content of `student.csv` file:

```
0
1
0
1
0
1
1
1
1
0
```